# BeautifulSoup can't scrape multiple pages

Tags: python, html, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape 20 pages of a website using BeautifulSoup. Each page has about 30 items and each of those items have 8 features which I want to retrieve and append as a tuple to a list called `res`.

Now the code below is supposed to retrieve all the items and their features from the 20 pages and store them to `res`, but it only seems to retrieve the first pages items and features, for some reason.

Any help is appreciated.

```
for i in range(30):

    r = requests.get('https://www.olx.ba/pretraga?trazilica=+golf+2&kategorija=18&stranica='+ str(i))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml') 

    all_items = soup.select('div#rezultatipretrage div.listitem.artikal.obicniArtikal.imaHover-disabled.i.index')

    for item in all_items:

        naziv = item.find('p', class_='na').text
        link = item.a['href']
        lokacija = item.find('div', class_='lokacijadiv').text.strip()
        godiste = item.find('span', class_='desnopolje').text
        gorivo = item.find_all('p', class_='polje')[1].find('span', class_='desnopolje').text

        if item.find('div', class_='cijena').span.text == 'PO DOGOVORU':
            cijena = 'PO DOGOVORU'
        else:
            cijena = item.find('div', class_='cijena').span.text[:-2].strip()
            cijena = int(cijena.replace('.',''))     

        stanje = item.find('div', class_='stanje k').text.strip()
        datum = item.find('div', class_='kada').text

        res.append((naziv, link, lokacija, godiste, gorivo, cijena, stanje, datum))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to only select all `<div>` with `listitem` class, to get all items from page, not only featured cars.

I made few changes and checks to your code to successfully scrape all 30 pages (I put `"-"` as default value to some fields, so check your result if it's correct):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from pprint import pprint

res = []
for i in range(30):
    r = requests.get('https://www.olx.ba/pretraga?trazilica=+golf+2&kategorija=18&stranica='+ str(i))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

    all_items = soup.select('div#rezultatipretrage div.listitem')

    for item in all_items:

        if not item.find('p', class_='na'):
            continue

        naziv = item.find('p', class_='na').text
        link = item.a['href']
        lokacija = item.find('div', class_='lokacijadiv').text.strip()
        godiste = item.find('span', class_='desnopolje').text if item.find('span', class_='desnopolje') else '-'
        try:
            gorivo = item.find_all('p', class_='polje')[1].find('span', class_='desnopolje').text
        except IndexError:
            gorivo = '-'

        if item.find('div', class_='cijena').span.text == 'PO DOGOVORU':
            cijena = 'PO DOGOVORU'
        else:
            cijena = item.find('div', class_='cijena').span.contents[-1][:-2].strip()
            cijena = int(cijena.replace('.',''))

        stanje = item.find('div', class_='stanje k').text.strip() if item.find('div', class_='stanje k') else '-'
        datum = item.find('div', class_='kada').text

        res.append((naziv, link, lokacija, godiste, gorivo, cijena, stanje, datum))

pprint(res)
```

This prints all info from 30 pages:

```
[('VW GOLF 5 2.0 TDI, 2005 god. Registrovan',
  'https://www.olx.ba/artikal/30396912/vw-golf-5-2-0-tdi-2005-god-registrovan/',
  'Živinice',
  '2005',
  'Dizel',
  8400,
  'KORIŠTENO',
  'Prije 4 dana'),
 ('VW GOLF 2 DIZEL TEK REGISTROVAN',
  'https://www.olx.ba/artikal/30512948/vw-golf-2-dizel-tek-registrovan/',
  'Ilijaš',
  '1985',
  'Dizel',
  1550,
  'KORIŠTENO',
  'Jučer, 16:05'),
 ('Golf 5 2.0 DIZEL SDI TEK REGISTROVAN',
  'https://www.olx.ba/artikal/30471980/golf-5-2-0-dizel-sdi-tek-registrovan/',
  'Travnik',
  '2004',
  'Dizel',
  7950,
  'KORIŠTENO',
  'Prije 5 dana'),
 ('Volkswagen Golf 6 2.0 TDI GTI-GTD-R LINE',
  'https://www.olx.ba/artikal/30478894/volkswagen-golf-6-2-0-tdi-gti-gtd-r-line/',
  'Banja Luka',
  '2010',
  'Dizel',
  19500,
  'KORIŠTENO',
  'Prije 7 dana'),
 ('VW GOLF 5,2.0 TDI,103 KW,04 G.P,6 BRZ.MOTOR U KVARU',
  'https://www.olx.ba/artikal/30485008/vw-golf-5-2-0-tdi-103-kw-04-g-p-6-brz-motor-u-kvaru/',
  'Prnjavor',
  '2004',
  'Dizel',
  5555,
  'KORIŠTENO',
  'Prije 4 dana'),
 ('VW Golf 6 2.0 TDI XENON-NAVI-KAMERA-KOZA',
  'https://www.olx.ba/artikal/30448040/vw-golf-6-2-0-tdi-xenon-navi-kamera-koza/',
  'Banja Luka',
  '2010',
  'Dizel',
  19500,
  'KORIŠTENO',
  'Prije 7 dana'),

...and so on.
```